# Strange type mismatch issue in Java

Tags: java, android, inheritance

In Java Android I have this situation:

MyActivity.java

```
public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
[...]
Fragment fragment = new myFragment();
[...]
}
```

Where myFragment is:

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {
[...]
}
```

Now,
if `myFragment` is declared inside `MyActivity.java` file all is ok and the code compiles; if I declare `myFragment` in another file (`myFragment.java`) I get "`Type mismatch: cannot convert from myFragment to Fragment`"...why?

Comment: Just a guess: Does `myFragment.java` import other namespaces than `MyActivity.java`? Namespace1.Fragment != Namespace2.Fragment...

Comment: If one is `android.app.Fragment` and the other is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` you'll see errors.

Comment: And please don't use lowercase names for classes.

Comment: Next time post your imports as well because as Dmitry Zaitsev said you have probably imported the wrong class because they have the same name.

Comment: @Sam is right...I had `android.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Thank you guys.

@BrianRoach oh, lowercase..it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you've extended `android.app.Fragment` in one case and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in another.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing the Correct Fragment in both places. The file where myFragment is defined as well as in MyActvity.